# ADODB parameter not sending input value

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, com, adodb

I have spent more time than i care to mention trying to sort this one out.  I am trying to call a stored procedure using adodb command execute in c#.  I am doing the same thing for all of my parameters but the first will always send 'system.object' instead of the value i want input.  I'd be very grateful for any help.

Here's the code:

```
ADODB.Connection con;
        ADODB.Command com;
        ADODB.Recordset rst;
        ADODB.Parameter prm;

        con = null;
        con = new ADODB.Connection();
        con.Provider = "SQLOLEDB.1";
        con.ConnectionString = "Description=MyDB;IntegratedSecurity=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=MyApp;WSID=MyServer;DATABASE=MyDB";
        con.Open(con.ConnectionString , null, null, 0);

        com = null;
        com = new ADODB.Command();
        com.CommandText = "MyStoredProc";
        com.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc;
        com.NamedParameters = true;
        com.Prepared = false;
        com.Name = ("MyStoredProc" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff"));

        prm = null;


        //Location parameter
        prm = com.CreateParameter("@LocationNameIn", DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 80, Convert.ToString("London"));
        com.Parameters.Append(prm);
        prm.Value = Convert.ToString("London");
        prm = null;

        //parameter
        prm = com.CreateParameter("@Time", DataTypeEnum.adDBTimeStamp, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 0, Convert.ToDateTime("01/12/2011 00:20"));
        com.Parameters.Append(prm);
        prm = null;

        //parameter
        prm = com.CreateParameter("@Param3", DataTypeEnum.adDouble, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 0, 1000.0);
        com.Parameters.Append(prm);
        prm = null;

        //parameter
        prm = com.CreateParameter("@Param4", DataTypeEnum.adDouble, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 0, -999);
        com.Parameters.Append(prm);
        prm = null;

        //parameter
        prm = com.CreateParameter("@Param5", DataTypeEnum.adDouble, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 0, 245.9);
        com.Parameters.Append(prm);
        prm = null;

        //parameter
        prm = com.CreateParameter("@Param6", DataTypeEnum.adDouble, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 0, -999);
        com.Parameters.Append(prm);

        prm = null;

        //parameter
        prm = com.CreateParameter("@Param7", DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 20, "South");
        com.Parameters.Append(prm);
        prm = null;

        //parameter
        prm = com.CreateParameter("@Param8", DataTypeEnum.adDouble , ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 0, 0);
        com.Parameters.Append(prm);
        prm = null;

        // parameter
        prm = com.CreateParameter("@Param9", DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 120, "BlahdiblahPC");
        com.Parameters.Append(prm);
        prm = null;


        com.ActiveConnection = con;
        object oRA = new object();
        object oPRM = new object();
        rst = com.Execute(out oRA, ref oPRM, (int)ExecuteOptionEnum.adExecuteRecord);
```

When i do a trace on the database i get the following:

> exec MyStoredProc @LocationNameIn='System.Object',@Time='2011-12-01
>   00:20:00',@Param3=1000,@Param4=-999,@Param5=245.90000000000001,@Param6=-999,@Param7='South',@Param8=0,@Param9='BlahdiblahP
>   C'

So all the parameters are working fine except for the first.  I have played about with datatypes for the parameter and with execution options for the command execute method but really don't have any idea where to start.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is this *really* your exact code? I doubt that `Convert.ToString("London")` will give you `System.Object` - is it possible that you're trying to convert some other data type to a string? (Calling `Convert.ToString` on a value which is known to be a string at compile time is pretty pointless.)

Comment: @Jon indeed, that does return the string `"London"`; I share your suspicions...

Comment: I'm afraid that is my real code (or at least a version that replicates the problem).  I forgot to take out the convert.tostring when i pasted it in - it was part of my fruitless attempts to get to the bottom of this rather than any functionality that i'm trying to implement.

Comment: Here's another symptom:  Throughout the whole process and afterwards, the value within the command.parameters[0] object is correct.  It is something to do with how it is being passed to the database.

Comment: @Neil can I ask another question... why are you using ADODB here, and not `SqlConnection`?

Comment: no particular reason - i am quite new to c#.  i have used adodb successfully before with vb but am not wed to it as a choice - is sqlconnection a better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* the problem is something to do with this:

```
object oRA = new object();
object oPRM = new object();
rst = com.Execute(out oRA, ref oPRM, (int)ExecuteOptionEnum.adExecuteRecord);
```

For a start, you don't need to assign a value to `oRA` here - it's an `out` parameter, so doesn't need to be definitely assigned. I don't have any experience with ADODB.Command, but I strongly suspect that the `System.Object` part is coming from `oPRM`. Just as an experiment, try:

```
object oRA;
object oPRM = "Some string";
rst = com.Execute(out oRA, ref oPRM, (int)ExecuteOptionEnum.adExecuteRecord);
```

... and see whether now the first parameter is "Some string". I wonder whether *if* you specify a parameter in the `Execute` call, it overwrites the first parameter stored in the parameter collection. If that's the case, you may want to set the value to `null` and see whether that is then ignored - I don't know enough about ADODB to say, but that's where I'd experiment. (And as per Marc's comment, I'd suggest using `SqlConnection` instead.)

Comment: Thankyou!  this works now.  In vb i was allowed to not pass oPRM and therefore didn't overwrite the value, whereas (obviously now i know what the problem is) in c# i couldn't omit the object.  It was overwriting the value of the first parameter.